# I want to get value of one textbox to anoter textbox in html/javascript or jsp/ajex

Tags: javascript, html

I am Trying to to get value of one text box which is entered by me in other non editable text box.
like
i am enter abc in one text box while entering Its automatically entered in second text box

plz help me

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="editable" />
<input type="text" id="uneditable" disabled="disabled" />
```

The script:

```
var uneditable = document.getElementById("uneditable");
document.getElementById("editable").onkeyup = function () {
    uneditable.value = this.value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var editable,noneditable;
window.onload = function () {    
    editable = document.getElementById('txtEditable');
    noneditable = document.getElementById('txtNonEditable');
    editable.onkeyup = function () {
        noneditable.value = editable.value;
    };
};
```